# println() statement of an object help. Does my professor want this output?

Tags: java, object

My professor has us modify her code for her labs. And for this lab in particular my professor has a println() statement that im not suppose to touch:

```
ArrayCollection ac = new ArrayCollection(ARRAY_SIZE);
```

So the code above instantiates an object called ac. Which is all fine and dandy, but my professor also has this statement in her code that I cannot modify:

```
System.out.println ("Collection contains:  " + ac);
```

So because of the line above, I get the following useless output:

> Collection contains: 
>   ArrayCollection{data=[Ljava.lang.Object;@24a20892, actualSize=3}

What can the output above tell me about object ac? Is the output completely useless or do you think that is what my professor could have intended. Sorry, I know this is a strange question, I'd appreciate anyone's comment about why my teacher left code like this(she takes points off for VERY minor mistakes >.<).

EDIT 9:48 AM:

ArrayCollection ac contained: {5,10,20} for the output I posted above

Comment: Interesting question, but there's really nobody who can tell you what your professor wants (i.e. answer the question) except your prof herself. Some of the guesses below make good points about how Java works, though. It might be good to refocus this to ask about what that print statement actually does and how the results could be meaningful, but that runs the risk of invalidating some of the existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the toString() method of `AbstractCollection` class within JDK.

```
public String toString() {
        Iterator<E> it = iterator();
        if (! it.hasNext())
            return "[]";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append('[');
        for (;;) {
            E e = it.next();
            sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
            if (! it.hasNext())
                return sb.append(']').toString();
            sb.append(',').append(' ');
        }
    }
```

It does what you may expect to see.

And if you don't want to "copy" the logic, inherits `ArrayCollection` from `AbstractCollection` for instance or directly use an `ArrayList`

Comment: Ahh... okay so the output I was recieving was actually taken from ArrayCollection's toString() method, that clears up everything now. Thanks Mik378!

Answer (score 1):

The hex-number after the @ is the object's hash code - in case of an object its reference. This might be of interest to her for automated testing.

Comment: Actually the number is the object's hash code as returned by the hashCode method. The default implementation of hashCode might use the memory address used for the object when it is created, or it might do something else.

Comment: I know, too lazy to elaborate ;)

Comment: Then why not just say "hash code" instead of "reference"?

Comment: Because as you said in case of an object it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your professor would like to have the content of the collection printed, and not the reference of the collection.

Here's how you can do it :

- Loop over the content of the collection.
- Inside this loop, call `toString()` on each object and accumulate the resulting strings in a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).
- Print this StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

It's not useless about, it's giving you the following data:

```
ArrayCollection{data=[Ljava.lang.Object;@24a20892, actualSize=3}
```

Can you look up each parameter...?

She's extending either [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) or [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class.

Edit: Yeah look at [AbstractCollection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html)

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that your `println` outputs the return value of `ArrayCollection.toString()`, which here gives you the information that (assuming that her implementation is reliable) the class `ArrayCollection` has at least two fields: `data` of type `Object[]`, and `actualSize`, probably of a numeric type, whose value for this instance is 3.

It seems reasonable to assume that `ArrayCollection` is an implementation of Java's `Collection` interface, backed by an array (`data`) which holds the actual elements.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `"Collection contains:  " + ac` is calling the `toString()` method on the `ac` object to get a String representation of the `ac` object.  Whenever you use `+` to concatenate a String with an object, the object is first converted to a String by calling the object's `toString()` method.

I think your teacher is expecting you to modify the `ArrayCollection` class so that `toString()` will produce a nicely formatted string representation.